# Rotated square during relativity

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I'm working with relativity and I can't seem to understand the following explanation for why a square with side length $L$ is perceived as rotated when travelling at a velocity $v$ (relativistic effect has to be taken into account):

[image]

I understand the first paragraph of 11.5. I also understand that photons from the right side of the square needs an extra time $L/c$ in order to reach our eyes, and in this time, the square then moves a distance $Lv/c$ sideways. However, I don't understand how figure 11.50, the one under 11.49, is constructed. I get lost when they use the words "point A", "point B" etc, what is point A exactly in this image? I have a hard time understanding this last figure. I'd be glad if someone could explain to me what really happens with more details, since I'm new to this concept and find it pretty hard to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

Points A and B are the top left and bottom left corners of the relativistically contracted square in Fig 11.49

If the observer had depth perception, they would see a parallelogram with near and far edges of length $L/\gamma = L \sqrt{1 - \beta^2}$ connected by 'slanted' edges of length $L \sqrt{1 + \beta^2}$. Fig 1.50 shows the bottom and left sides of this parallelogram.

However, the tacit assumption is that the viewer lacks depth perception, so they see the near side of length $L \sqrt{1-\beta^2}$ trailed by the AB side of apparent length $L \beta$. This is also how they would see a stationary square rotated at an angle of $\theta = \arcsin(\beta)$ relative to their line of sight, which is the point of Fig 11.51.

The phrase "looks like" is a little ambiguous, but at least Morin made this one of the worked problems.

Answer (score 0):

The middle figure is what the left figure looks like to you.  The right figure shows the middle figure looks the same as a rotated square to you.

[image]